# Why doesn't the post picture load if the extension is name_of_pic.JPG?

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, jekyll-theme

The top of my .markdown file in the jekyll theme is as follows:

```
---
layout: post
title: xyz
description: xyz
img: /img/1.JPG
---
```

The picture does not load if the extension is .JPG, even though the picture's extension in the _img/ folder is .JPG

It works if the extension in the code is changed to `.jpg`.

Everything works fine when I jekyll serve it locally but this happens when I push my changes to github and try to view my changes on github pages

I could do a patch up like this everywhere but I would like to understand why I have to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just tested your code on [this forked repository](https://github.com/djacquel/miyesven.github.io).

If I test this [locally](http://127.0.0.1:4000/portfolio/) or [on github-pages](https://djacquel.github.io/miyesven.github.io/portfolio/), this is how things are going :

```
| _portofolio file |  image name  | front matter | HTTP status   |
------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1_project        |  1.jpg       |  1.jpg       | 200 OK        |
| 2_project        |  2.jpg       |  2.JPG       | 404 Not found |
| 3_project        |  3.JPG       |  3.jpg       | 404 Not found |
| 4_project        |  4.JPG       |  4.JPG       | 200 OK        |
```

All those results are due to both local and github webservers case sensitivity. Upper cased letters are not considered to be equal to lower cased letters (a!=A).

[For Why case-sensitivity ? see this question on stack webmaster.](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/90339/why-are-urls-case-sensitive)

And this :

> The picture does not load if the extension is .JPG, even though the picture's extension in the _img/ folder is .JPG

is supposed to work, just like in our fourth test case.